# How to de-interleave a vector?

Tags: matlab, vector, cell-array

How to re-order a vector efficiently? The numbers represent 'frames' in a movie that are sorted in the following order:

```
a=[1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9];
```

the result should be a cell array with the different streams starting with 1,2 and 3:

```
b{1}=[1 2 3];
b{2}=[4 5 6];
b{3}=[7 8 9];
```

Right now I'm using a `for` loop, but I have a hunch it could be done more efficiently (i.e. less lines of code, less time to run) than a `for` loop:

```
for ind=1:3
    b{ind}=a(ind:3:end);
end
```

The final code has `ind=1:30000` instead of `ind=1:3`; is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is the increment constant `numel(ind)` or is it constant `3` for all cases? Will `numel(a)` (9 in your example) always be a multiple of increment-constant (3 in your example)?

Comment: excellent question, sorry for the late reply. The increment in the original code is a constant `3` in all cases. `numel(a)` will always be a multiple of that constant. The concept is, you have a movie with _3 independent streams of content_. What I want to do is to reorder them to access these 3 different streams more conveniently in separate variables (where post-processing can happen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) `a` to the required shape and use [matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) to access its relevant rows.

```
bmat = reshape(a,k,[]);  %k equals 3 in your example
%bmat(1,:) will be your b{1},   bmat(2,:) --> b{2},   and so on.
```

If you really need to convert it to a cell like in your question then use [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) as follows:

```
b = mat2cell(bmat, ones(k,1));
```

Comment: Ok, so I realize, the real problem comes from reshaping the 3D matrix, I'm fiddling around to reshaping it into 4D, but it's sort of hard to wrap your head around (e.g. a is 200x400x10000, x/y/time dimension). This I think already helped